# remove duplicated lines and sort the table in Perl

Tags: perl

I have a table like this:

```
  + chr13   25017807    6
  + chr10   128074490   1
  - chr7    140968671   1
  + chr10   79171976    3
  - chr7    140968671   1
  + chr12   4054997     6
  + chr13   25017807    6
  + chr15   99504255    6
  - chr8    91568709    5
```

It has been already read into Perl as a string variable (the returned value of an external shell script). I need to remove the duplicated lines and sort the table by the last column, and then print it out. How should I do it in Perl? Thanks!

Comment: Well, you `split` the string into lines, then `split` each line into fields, and `sort` by the last column. After that, you `join` the fields back together to form lines, and `join` those back to a single string: `join "\n", map join(" ", @$_), sort { $a->[-1] <=> $b->[-1] } map [split], grep {not redundant($_)} split /\n/, $string` or something like that

Comment: How should you achieve whatnot in whatnow? What's a string variable? What are the redundant lines? Hey, you want to sort that last column, that's easy enough, perldoc -f sort will sort you out.

Comment: @amon Could you please give me an example? I am totally a newbie to Perl.

Comment: @Runner How about you give us an example instead. That's how things work around here.

Comment: @TLP, I thought the table I posted was the example. Line 5 and 7 are redundant as they are the same as Line 3 and 1. Thanks!

Comment: @Runner Well, with that definition of “redundant” we just repace `redundant($_)` in my above code with `$seen{$_}++`, with a hash `my %seen` declared in a surrounding scope.

Comment: @Runner You will find that "redundant" is sadly inadequate to describe the variety of features available in the Perl language. So, how would you describe the redundant characters in Lord of the Rings? Hey, how would you list the redundant symbols in the ascii table? So, in my living room I have 5 plants. Which ones are redundant?

Comment: @TLP, sorry about the wording, I have edited the question. Is "duplicated" appropriate?

Comment: @Runner If by "duplicate" you mean "identically duplicate lines", then yes, I suppose that's better. However, you should really rethink your life philosophy if you consider "redundant" and "duplicate" to be equivalent.

Comment: @amon, I am still trying to understand what you wrote. Did you wrote the code in a reverse way (i.e., `split /\n/, $string` is the first code, and `join "\n"` is the last one)?

Comment: @Runner yes. The fully paranthesized version would look like `join("\n", map({join(" ", @$_)} ... split(/\n/, $string)))`. The data “flows” from right to left in an APL-esque way through various transforms. Note: `map EXPR, LIST` is the same as `map {BLOCK} LIST`; the first argument is not initially evaluated, but used as a function. The `split` without further arguments splits `$_` at every whitespace character (similar to `split /\s+/, $_`). `[...]` creates an anonymous array. `$a->[-1]` accesses the last field of the anonymous array `$a`.

Comment: @amon, thanks a lot for your detailed explanation. Now I can understand most of your code except `grep {$seen{$_}++}`. Could you please explain this code?

Comment: @Runner It's `grep {not $seen{$_}++}`. `$seen{$_}++` increments that hash entry (HE) in `%seen` whose key is the current line. The increment does not happen immediately. So when a new line encountered, `$seen{$_}++` evaluates to zero (false), but sets the HE to one (true). When a duplicate line is encountered, the previous value is returned, which is always a true value. The `not` negates the truthiness, so a new line returns true, a seen line is false. The `grep {BLOCK} LIST` function returns all elements from the list which are considered to be true by the block when passed as `$_`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the data is contained in the string `$string`, this solution would work:

```
my %seen;  # just needed to remove duplicates
my $deduped_string =
  join "\n",                     # 6. join the lines to a single string
  map  { join(" ", @$_) }        # 5. join the fields of each line to a string
  sort { $a->[-1] <=> $b->[-1] } # 4. sort arrayrefs by last field, numerically
  map  { [split] }               # 3. split line into fields, store in anon arrayref
  grep { not $seen{$_}++ }       # 2. dedupe the lines
  split /\n/, $string;           # 1. split string into lines
```

This gargantuan expression executes from bottom towards top (or right to left). It consists of multiple composable transformers and filters:

- `map {BLOCK} LIST` applies the code in the block to each value of the list. It transforms the list element-wise.
- `grep {BLOCK} LIST` selects those elements from the list where the block returns true. It therefore filters the list and only outputs elements that satisfy a certain condition.
- `sort {BLOCK} LIST` resorts the list. The block must return -1 if `$a` is less than `$b`, 1 if it is greater, or zero when equal. The `<=>` operator compares scalars numerically in this fashion. If the sort function is omitted, string comparision is used.
- `join STRING, LIST` concatenates the elements of the list with the string in between.
- `split REGEX, STRING` splits the string into pieces. The regex matches the delimiter (not usually returned). `split` and `join` can be considered inverse operations. If the string is omitted, `$_` is used. When the regex is omitted, it works similarly to `split /\s+/, $_`, i.e. splits at every whitespace character.

This solution uses at its heart the *Schwartzian Transform*, a technique/idiom that enables cheap sorting by expensive-to-calculate keys. In it's general form, it is

```
my @sorted_data =
  map  { $_->[0] }                  # 3. map back to the orginal value
  sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] }      # 2. sort by the special key
  map  { [$_, create_the_key($_)] } # 1. annotate each value with a key
  @data;
```

In my specific case, the special key is the last column of each record; To obtain the original data (or an equivalent form) from the annotated data I join the fields together. As *mpapec* points out, I could also have carried the original line through the transform; this would preserve the original alignment of the lines.

Comment: you can `map [$_, split],` to save original line in case separator is multiple/various white spaces, and later `map $_->[0],` instead of joining by single space.

Comment: Thank you very much for these clear codes and explanations. I learned a lot from your answer. Combined with perldoc, I have understood all your code except `@$_`, could you please also explain this usage?

Comment: @Runner Sure. `$_` is the topic variable and holds the “current item”. In the 5th `map`, it holds an array reference of the fields. We need to pass all items to `join`, which expects a list of values. If the length is known, we could `join " ", $_->[0], $_->[1], ...` but that is tedious. Rather, I step through the array reference to the original array. `@` is used for array dereference here; It can be used like `@{must_return_arrayref()}`. The curlies can sometimes be omitted. As arrays are flattened inside arglists, `join " ", @$_` joins all elements in the referenced array.

Answer (score 1):

Filters out duplicate lines, and sorts by the last column at the end,

```
perl -ane 'next if $s{$_}++; push @r,[$_,@F]}{ print $$_[0] for sort { $$a[-1] <=> $$b[-1] } @r' file
```

Almost same as,

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, "file" or die $!;
my (%seen_line, @result_unique_lines);
while (<$fh>) {

  # $_ => content of current line

  # skip current if it's duplicate
  next if $seen_line{$_}++;

  my @line_values = split;
  push @result_unique_lines, [$_, @line_values];
}
close $fh;

# sort lines
@result_unique_lines = sort { $a->[-1] <=> $b->[-1] } @result_unique_lines;

for my $aref (@result_unique_lines) {

  my $line = $aref->[0];
  print $line;  
}
```

Comment: I am new to Perl, so it is really difficult for me to understand the one-liner you posted. It would be great if you can explain the code a little bit or give an equivalent verbose version of the code. Thanks a lot.

Comment: thanks a lot! I learned a lot from this Q&A. I also wondered what the parameters "-an" means in your one-liner. I couldn't find an answer by `man perl`.

Comment: np, `-n` makes a while loop around code looping/reading lines from file given on command line, and `-a` splits every line by whitepaces and puts result in `@F` array. It's in `perldoc perlrun`

Answer (score 1):

For a beginner, I'd do it like this:

```
use strict; use warnings;

my $file = "table.txt";
open(my $fh, "<", $file) || die "Can't open $file: $!\n";

my @lines;

# read the file and save a transformed version to @lines
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
   chomp($line);                   # remove final newline
   $line =~ s/ +/:/gi;             # make ":" the new separator
   my @fields = split(/:/,$line);  # split at the separator
   my $newline = "$fields[4]:$fields[1]:$fields[2]:$fields[3]"; # reorder fields
   push(@lines, $newline);         # save the new line
}

@lines = sort(@lines);  # sort lines alphabetically:
                        # duplicate lines are now consecutive
my $uniqline="";        # the last unique line

foreach my $line (@lines) {
   # do this if the current line isn't string-equal to the last line
   # (i.e. skip all lines that are equal to the previous line)
   if ($uniqline ne $line) {
      $uniqline = $line;  # remember the last line
      # print fields in original order
      my @fields = split(/:/,$line);
      printf("  %s %7s %11s %s\n",$fields[1],$fields[2],$fields[3],$fields[0]);
   }
}
```

I got slightly different result...

```
  +   chr10   128074490 1
  -    chr7   140968671 1
  +   chr10    79171976 3
  -    chr8    91568709 5
  +   chr12     4054997 6
  +   chr13    25017807 6
  +   chr15    99504255 6
```

Comment: I took the liberty of modernizing the code to comply with `use strict`: All variables are now declared properly. I also read the file in a `while` loop, and use lexical filehandles. The comments now provide a step-by-step explanation how this solution works, although I did not remove some oddities: (1) The last col is a number, why are you using string comparision in sort? (2) Why did you change the separator? There is no benefit I can see. (3) Introducing slices would make this so much more readable, (4) You might want to explain the need for `%11s` in `printf` (`%11d` is marginally better).

Comment: Thanks amon. It's look better.